# To keep my schengen visa valid, do I have to enter within FIRST 90 days of validity?

Tags: schengen-visas, multiple-entry, itineraries, long-term

I was given a multiple entry schengen visa for 60 months with no restrictions. To keep my schengen visa valid, do I have to enter within **first** 90 days of validity **OR** can I enter next year too?

FYI, I was not able to make the trip I got the visa for because of personal reasons, and I have entered the schengen area on previous visas.

Comment: Is there any restriction listed on the visa? What made you think that you have to immediately enter?

Comment: Theoretically the visa can be **revoked**, since you are not using it as was originaly intended. You could inform the consulate now why you have canceled your intended visit (they may ask you the same question at the next visa application) and that you plan to use it next year. This could forstall any revolking or questions when entering the first time. Otherwise the visa remains valid.

Comment: @littleadv Its a multiple entry visa sticker. No restrictions. Immediate entry was off internet wisdom too. Your final thoughts ? Others ?

Comment: "Internet wisdom"?  Can you link to any of this wisdom so we can see whether it's coming from anyone who ought to know what they're talking about?

Answer (score 5):

A 5-year multiple-entry visa is basically the highest possible privilege which can be granted to a Schengen visitor.

It is normally granted after multiple visas of increasing durations or if your circumstances are very favourable.

In short, it means “we trust you, you can come and go as you want”, as long as you continue to meet the conditions of the visa, i.e. the 90/180 rule, no overstaying, no working in Schengen, and so on.

In theory, you are expected to do what you said you would do on your first visit, with minor changes. But:

- such visas can be granted in circumstances where you just say “I will come multiple times over the next few years for a given reason” (for instance, you need to visit a local subsidiary of the company your work for on a regular basis). In this case no issue at all.
- If you actually gave plans for one specific trip and nothing else, in theory you should do that trip, with minor variations, before you can do whatever you want. But this is not your first overall visit to Schengen, and whatever country granted you the visa trusts you enough that it most probably doesn’t matter at all. Border officers probably yawn when they see your visa.

There is no obligation to use the visa within a given period.

If you want to be absolutely safe you can contact the embassy or consulate which issued your visa and advise them of your change in plans, but I really don’t foresee a problem.